# How to expand function $\cos(y+i\log{x})$ in powers of $x$?

Tags: series-expansion

I have the following, probably very simple question.
How can I get $\it{Mathematica}$ to power expand function $\cos(y+i \log(x))$ in powers of $x$? This function obeys a well defined Laurent expansion about $x=0$ and I would like  $\it{Mathematica}$  to give $\frac1{x}e^{i y}/2+x e^{-iy}/2$ upon evaluation of

```
Series[Cos[y + I Log[x]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

However, the result is

```
Cos[y + I Log[x]]
```

i.e. the original expression. I can bet that in some circumstances such expansion worked without any effort from my side.

I wonder what is the right way to obtain the expansion of the function $\cos(y+i \log(x))$ in powers of $x$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to get the desired output is to use [`TrigToExp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TrigToExp.html)

```
TrigToExp[Cos[y + I Log[x]]]
(* E^(I y)/(2 x) + 1/2 E^(-I y) x *)
```

Comment: This indeed works, thank you.